# How to fix undefined method 'data_store' for Resque:Module

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, resque-scheduler

I am developing a Rails 4.2 application, When I run command: "rake resque:scheduler" I got the error

```sh
        [WARNING] Recurly logger has been disabled. If you wish to use it,
        only do so in a non-production environment and make sure
        the `RECURLY_INSECURE_DEBUG` environment variable is set to `true`.
The PGconn, PGresult, and PGError constants are deprecated, and will be
removed as of version 1.0.

You should use PG::Connection, PG::Result, and PG::Error instead, respectively.

Called from /Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in `block in load_dependency'
resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-04-26T16:18:58+07:00: Starting
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `data_store' for Resque:Module
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-30e40f897b52/lib/resque/scheduler/locking.rb:100:in `redis_master_version'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-30e40f897b52/lib/resque/scheduler/locking.rb:62:in `supports_lua?'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-30e40f897b52/lib/resque/scheduler/locking.rb:86:in `build_master_lock'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-30e40f897b52/lib/resque/scheduler/locking.rb:58:in `master_lock'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-30e40f897b52/lib/resque/scheduler/locking.rb:66:in `master?'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-30e40f897b52/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:59:in `block in run'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-30e40f897b52/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:56:in `loop'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-30e40f897b52/lib/resque/scheduler.rb:56:in `run'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-30e40f897b52/lib/resque/scheduler/cli.rb:117:in `run_forever'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bundler/gems/resque-scheduler-30e40f897b52/lib/resque/scheduler/tasks.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/bugsnag-5.4.1/lib/bugsnag/rake.rb:12:in `execute_with_bugsnag'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/bacdo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => resque:scheduler
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Can you show me how to fix this issue?
Thank you very much.

I am in MacOS Mojave (10.14.4), ruby 2.4.3, Redis 4.0.14

Answer (score 0):

update your version of resque: https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler/pull/670